# What is the meaning of template parameters in boost::any_range?

Tags: c++, boost, type-erasure, boost-type-erasure

I've been surfing the internet in search of some well-documented reference for stuff like `boost::any_range`, but all I've managed to find is an [official source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) which only gives a brief explanation of what `any_range` is about and presents some basic signatures. I'm looking for something which would explain it in detail.

A basic template for `any_range` looks like this:

```
template<
    class Value
  , class Traversal
  , class Reference
  , class Difference
  , class Buffer = any_iterator_default_buffer
>
class any_range;
```

What is the meaning of each template parameter, and what values can it hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`any_range` is a type-erased container which allows you to store ranges which have at least the capabilities required by the template parameters you supply.

It is based on `any_iterator`, for which you can find detailed information in [this article](https://www.artima.com/articles/on-the-tension-between-object-oriented-and-generic-programming-in-c).

Note that the template parameters in the documentation are missing some default arguments which are in the code itself. The real definition has:

```
template<
    class Value
  , class Traversal
  , class Reference = Value&
  , class Difference = std::ptrdiff_t
  , class Buffer = use_default
>
class any_range
```

The `Value` parameter specifies the type of the elements exposed by the range. So an `any_range<int,...>` may store a `std::vector<int>`, or a `std::list<int>`, etc.

The `Traversal` parameter specifies the category of range which is allowed, e.g. random access, forward, input. It can be one of the options from [iterator_categories](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp). An `any_range<int, random_access_tag, ...>` would be able to store a `std::vector<int>`, but not a `std::list<int>`, because `std::list` is only bidirectional, not random-access.

The `Reference` parameter indicates which type should be returned when you dereference iterators for the range. It defaults to `Value&`, and that's fine for most cases. (One case where it would *not* be okay is if your ranges return proxy references, like `std::vector<bool>` does)

The `Difference` indicates which type should be returned when you subtract one iterator for the range from another, getting the difference between them. This defaults to `std::ptrdiff_t` which is also fine for most cases.

Finally, the `Buffer` parameter indicates how to store the underlying type-erased range. This defaults to `any_iterator_default_buffer`, which stores the underlying range inside the `any_range` object so long as it's 64 bytes or less. Otherwise it heap allocates it. Other options for this are `any_iterator_buffer<MaxStackSize>`, `any_iterator_heap_only_buffer`, and `any_iterator_stack_only_buffer<StackSize>`.

(Sources: I got all of this by reading the source code)